# Nested layout weight for equal spacing and performace

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I got two views which are equally distributed on my main layout.But my two views in tern have nested childs which are again equally spaced.I am using nested layout weight's which is working fine. Whether nested weights effects the performance.What is the work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every view — or worse, every layout manager — that you add to your
>   application comes at a cost: initialization, layout and drawing become
>   slower. The layout pass can be especially expensive when you nest
>   several LinearLayout that use the weight parameter, which requires the
>   child to be measured twice.

Refer: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html

You can use a RelativeLayout in most cases to avoid such expensive measurements. In a RelativeLayout, views are aligned with their parent, with the RelativeLayout itself, or with other views.

To clearly understand how the views are positioned with respect to each other, a wireframe of the layout can be captured by using **HierarchyViewer** perspective of Android SDK.

Comment: Is the performance relevant at all in this case? I mean, even if children will have to be measured twice; we're talking about a millisecond or two?